# How to resize or drag the length of a div after dropping in to the container div to cover another div in time table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]After I drop the job div in to the time table, I need to drag the dropped job div to fill next div to extend the time. Example: If I drop 'job-1' on 9am block but this job needs 3 hours, therefore, I need to extend or drag the 'Job-1' div till 11am block to fill in 3 block for job-1. Likewise, I need to drop the job-2 on empty slot and just to the same like for job-1.

Thank you in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.job').draggable({
    revert: true
  });

  $('.container').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(e, ui) {

      $(this).html(ui.draggable.remove().html());
      $(this).droppable('destroy');
      $(this).addClass("dropped");
    },
    over: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).addClass("dropped");
    },
    out: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).removeClass("dropped");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.job {
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #B9CD6D;
}

.dropJob {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 12vh repeat(9, 1fr);
}

.dropJob div {
  border: 2px solid #1974a8;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  background: #a5d5ff;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.dropJob div:nth-of-type(10n) {
  border-right: 2px solid #1974a8;
}

.dropJob div:nth-last-child(-n + 10) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1974a8;
}

.dropJob div:nth-child(10n + 1) {
  background: #32a4e5;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #103143;
  color: #e3f5ff;
}

.dropped {
  background: green !important;
}

.timing {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 12vh repeat(9, 1fr);
}

.timing div {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #103143;
  color: #e3f5ff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #1974a8;
}

.scheduleContain {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="job">Job 1</div>
<div class="job">Job 2</div>
<div class="job">Job 3</div>
<div class="job">Job 4</div>

<div class="scheduleContain">
  <div class="timing">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>9am</div>
    <div>10am</div>
    <div>11am</div>
    <div>12am</div>
    <div>1pm</div>
    <div>2pm</div>
    <div>3pm</div>
    <div>4pm</div>
    <div>5pm</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropJob">
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `width` not work? What do you mean "resize"? Is it visually, or in a way so that you cannot place things on the 10 am and 11 am after resize-dropping?

Comment: I need to drop in to one block and extend/drag in to other blocks.

Comment: Like you can see in the above pic